# Gradle sonarRunner and Sonar 3.6.0: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Task null does not exist

Tags: gradle, sonar-runner

I updated our sonar as described in the [Upgrade Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Upgrade+guide). After doing so, I tried to invoke our Jenkins build that normally feeds the sonar. We use gradle 1.6 (Wrapper) and the buildin sonarRunner.

After all the tests have been executed, the sonarRunner produces the following error:

```
14:50:27.684 [QUIET] [system.out] 14:50:27.682 INFO  - Load batch settings
14:50:27.763 [QUIET] [system.out] 14:50:27.763 INFO  - User cache: /***/***/.sonar/cache
14:50:27.766 [QUIET] [system.out] 14:50:27.766 INFO  - Install plugins
14:50:28.017 [QUIET] [system.out] 14:50:28.017 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
14:50:28.045 [QUIET] [system.out] 14:50:28.045 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://***/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
14:50:29.947 [QUIET] [system.out] 14:50:29.947 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate    
14:50:33.249 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on task artifact state cache (/***/***/.gradle/1.6/taskArtifacts).
14:50:33.250 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
14:50:33.250 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':sonarRunner'
14:50:33.250 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :sonarRunner FAILED
14:50:33.254 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:50:33.255 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:50:33.255 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:50:33.255 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:50:33.255 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
14:50:33.255 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Task null does not exist
```

Before the upgrade, this worked. Has anyone else encountered this problem yet?

Comment: Best ask on the Sonar list.

Answer (score 0):

Meh. Unloading the old sonar web application and loading the new version didn't work correctly.

I restarted the tomcat and the problem was gone.

**Have you tried turning it off and on again?**